# Adjective rules

Tags: adjectives

First and foremost, I am a beginner, and I have just started studying Japanese. At my university we use Shokyu Nihongo 1 as the main student, so let's get to the point. In chapter 2 there are rules about adjectives. Thus far I understand the order of adjectives:

1. Noun は Adjective (い-adj or な-adj) です
2. Adjective (い-adj or な-adj) Noun は です

> 富士山は高い山です。

However I don't understand the difference between rule #2 and #3

**The rule #3 is as follows:
Adjective (い-adj or な-adj) Noun は ~ です**

> e.g. そのあかいかみはしょっけんですか。いいえ、このあかいかみはしょっけんではありません。

In my book rules #2 and #3 are the same, however, I may not see the difference so I would be glad for the explanation of rule #3

Comment: The rule #3 is as follows: Adjective (い-adj or な-adj) Noun は ~ です e.g. そそのあかいかみはしょっけんですか。いええ、このあかいかみはしょっけんでわりません。I forgot to highlight it. Sorry.

Comment: Example for rule 3 is not mine. It is an example of the authors of this book.

Comment: I corrected the typos. Thanks, for noticing them.

Comment: After the correction of the typos, they are copied verbatim.

Comment: If this book really has those typos it seems extremely unreliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things potentially going on here there are confusing you.

The first that comes to mind is a grammatical point being somewhat obscured by the use of *formal* structures.

To me, it looks like there are three different types of sentences you're learning to express here.

1. **Noun Phrase** is **Adjective**
2. It is **Noun Phrase**.
3. **Noun Phrase** is **Noun Phrase**

These would correspond to the following three rules for Japanese

1. Noun は Adjective (い-adj or な-adj) です
2. Adjective (い-adj or な-adj) Noun です (Notice this differs from your rule 2)
3. Adjective (い-adj or な-adj) Noun は [Noun Phrase] です

These are expressing three rather different ideas.

Examples first in English.

1. The red book is expensive.
2. It is a tall mountain.
3. The young woman is a student.

In Japanese, using plain forms (which you may not have learned yet), these would be expressed as

1. [赤]{あか}い[本]{ほん}は[高]{たか}い
2. [高]{たか}い[山]{やま}だ
3. [若]{わか}い[女]{おんな}は[学生]{がくせい}だ

To move these into a more formal register, you would change them as follows.

- For sentences ending in an い-adjective, the sentence is made formal by adding です
- For sentences ending in だ, change だ to です

So, applying these to the three sentences above (to make them formal), you get

1. [赤]{あか}い[本]{ほん}は[高]{たか}いです
2. [高]{たか}い[山]{やま}です
3. [若]{わか}い[女]{おんな}は[学生]{がくせい}です

There is no Japanese grammatical structure that is composed as

- <*Noun phrase*>はです。

If you're starting with <*Noun phrase*>は and ending with です then between the two you need to be saying something about <*Noun phrase*>.

So, it's ungrammatical to say

> あかいほんはです

> The read book is .... <*what?  you haven't said*>

But you can say

> あかいほんです

> It's a red book.

You can also say

> あかいほんはこれです

> The red book is this.

## Conclusion

I suspect that the there is a typo in your rule two.  It should perhaps read

2. Adjective (い-adj or な-adj) Noun  です

Notice the omission of the particle は.

Comment: You can also say これは赤い本です, but that changes the subject. ;)

Comment: @wanwandrew Indeed.  I would say that corresponds to the OP's rule 3.  Either way.  I really wanted to write 赤い本は僕の本です but then I figured I'd already indulged in grammatical details (like formal vs plain form) that the OP might not have already learned.

Comment: I could feel it. I could feel it through your typing. lol.